# Help understanding proof that uses Sylow Theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p>q$ be primes. Show that if $p-1$ is not divisible by $q$ then there is exactly one group of order $pq.$

Please help me to understand a few questions that I specified in the below proof.

Proof. Using Sylow Theorems, we can calculate that $n_{p}=n_{q}=1$. (I understand these calculation parts just fine using Sylow Theorems). And, we can denote each of these unique Sylow p-group and Sylow q-group as $P$ and $Q$ respectively, and note that since each is unique, each is normal in $G.$

Then, we note that $Q \cong \mathbb{Z}_{q}$ and $P \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p}$. (This part, I'm not sure I understand ...I kind of recall a theorem saying that any two groups with prime order are isomorphic to one another. Is that where this is coming from?)

Then, we know that $QP \leq G$. (I don't understand this part. How do we know this? It's supposed to follow from $Q$ and $P$ being normal?)

Then, we note that $|QP|=\frac{|Q||P|}{Q\cap P}=qp=|G|$. (This part I understand just fine). Therefore $G=QP$.

Then we can see that since $P$ and $Q$ are normal in $G$, then $QP=Q \times P$, that is, $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{q} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p} \cong Z_{pq}$ (I don't understand this part. Does it have to do with external direct products? I know it has to do partly with the fact that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime).

Then it is clear that every subgroup with order $pq$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ up to isomorphism, which completes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Q\cong Z_{q}$: there is a theorem says there is only one group of prime order $q$, $Z_{q}$. This theorem follows from Lagrange's theorem. (cor. 10 page 90 in Dummit and Foote.)

$QP\leq G$: by a theorem: if $H\leq G$ and $K\unlhd G$, then $HK\leq G$. (cor. 15 page 94 in Dummit and Foote.)

$QP\cong Q\times P$: by this theorem: if $H,K\unlhd G$ and $H\cap K=1$, then $HK\cong H\times K$. (thm 9, page 171 in Dummit and Foote.)

$Z_{q}\times Z_{p}\cong Z_{qp}$: by proposition: $Z_{m}\times Z_{n}\cong Z_{mn}$ if and only if $(m,n)=1$. (prop. 6, page 163 in Dummit and Foote.)

$Q\times P\cong Z_{q}\times Z_{p}$: you can prove this: if $f_{1}:H_{1}\to K_{1}, f_{2}:H_{2}\to K_{2}$ are group isomorphisms, then $f:H_{1}\times H_{2}\to K_{1}\times K_{2}$ defined by $f(h_{1},h_{2})=(f_{1}(h_{1}),f_{2}(h_{2}))$ is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed. That's my same textbook, too. Now I know where to look to justify each steps and use them more going forward.